# Creation of a new dataframe column based onn value of another column string value

Tags: python-3.x

Hi All I am new to Python, and I am trying to solve a problem that I want to create a new data frame column based on another existing column, If the existing column value contains a specific sub string then the new column value should be the existing column value else the new column value should be existing string value appended with another string

I have tried different methods to solve the same, even the existing column can contain null values also. Putting my code part below.

```
df['new_column']=[df['existing_col'] if (x.str.contains("@gmail.com")==True) else df['existing_col']+"append_val" for x in df['existing_col']]
print(df['new_column'])
```

Actual result::`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: use `x.contains()` instead of `x.str.contains()`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Still getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: I am new to python and is trying to learn this data frame concepts deeply, suggest me some good learning sites too